# jQuery text in div to input in admin

Tags: php, jquery, admin

One page I have articles with prices.  I would like to do administration. When I am administrator and I would click on price input field text would show.

My code for this:

```
$('#priceBig').click(function() {
    var originalelement = this;
    var dishID = this.id;
    var currentText = $.trim($(this).text())

    $(this).hide().before('<input class="input" id="'+dishID+'" style="padding:3px; text-align:left; font-size:17px; width:50px;"  type="text" value="'+currentText+'"/>');     

    $('.input').live('change', function() {
        var picaID = this.id;
        var price = $(this).val();
        var thisparam = this;

        $.post('<?= site_url('dish/changePicaBigPrice') ?>',{ picaID : picaID, price:price}, 
        function(data) { 
            $(thisparam).remove();  
            $(originalelement).text(price).fadeIn(1000);
        },'text');

    });

});
```

But this doesn't work because jQuery store all originalelement objects and every change of price change all originalelements which were clicked before...

I hope I was clear what I want to do.

I would like to click on price, change and one I go on other price

Comment: Not really that clear, but it sounds like...you're running into the problem that ANYONE can click this item and make a change...not just the admin?

Comment: no part of code where i check if user is admin is omited... admin can click on price which is in div and instead of div, input with current price would show and if admin change this price and click in other price or something else new price would show in clicked div

Comment: my code would work if on page would bi just one article with price...

Answer (score 0):

I believe my old answer won't work.

New tactics - save the old ID in an attribute on the new input you create, and use it in the success handler.

```
$('#priceBig').click(function() {
    var currentText = $.trim($(this).text())

    var input = $('<input />')
      .addClass('input')
      .attr('type', 'text')
      .attr('orig-id', $(this).attr('id'))
      .val(currentText)
      .bind('change', function () {
        var t = $(this);
        var price = t.val();
        var origID = t.attr('orig-id');

        $.post('<?= site_url('dish/changePicaBigPrice') ?>',{ picaID : origID, price:price},
        function(data) {
            t.remove();
            $('#' + origID).text(price).fadeIn(1000);
        },'text');
      });

    $(this).hide().before(input);
});
```

EDIT: fixed typo in *var origID = t.attr('orid-id');*

EDIT: change *picaID* to *origID* in the $.post parameters

Comment: wait. why is the change handler defined inside the click handler?

Comment: when i click on div instead of div input is shown and change handler is refer to input not on div object so your previous help is not ql, if you had any other idea how i could implement this please tell....

Comment: your code doesn't work... when i click and change nothing happen, input is still shown...

Comment: still doesn't work, now i can change price but new price doesn't show in previous div

Comment: can i refer jquery object with class = "bigPrice" and id = "1"  $('.bigPrice#'+origID).show().text(price).fadeIn(1000); doesn't work

Comment: ok this work: $(".priceBig").filter('#'+origID).show().text(price).fadeIn(1000);